# Lights pulsating rhythmically

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, fire-hazard

I noticed lights on multiple circuits rhythmically dimming. Not all lights, but seemingly random lights. I had no major appliances running at all. I had one small appliance running in the kitchen (a kettle) with a max draw of 10amps (plugged into a grounded 20 amp outlet on an otherwise unused 20 amp breaker). After unplugging it, the lights stopped pulsing. To rule out coincidence, I plugged in the kettle once more and turned it on. The lights resumed their pulsing. Well, that could still be a coincidence. I’m a huge skeptic and this doesn’t make sense, so I turned the kettle off and unplugged it once more. No more pulsing. We have upgraded to a 200 amp service from 100 a couple months ago. I highly doubt it’s overload as the appliance draws 10 on a 20. I briefly flipped on a light that shares the same circuit as the kettle while it was running and it was *not* pulsing. I guess my question is… what could cause this issue? The lights with the worst pulsing were upstairs in my kids’ rooms. Totally separate breaker.

Comment: Does moving the kettle to a different circuit change the pulsing behavior?

Comment: That’s an excellent question. My kids are attempting sleep now, but this is the first thing I’ll check in the morning.

Comment: defective kettle

Comment: Type of light bulbs will help also.  LEDs are more sensitive than other older types.

Comment: -crip659, we are slowly changing the lighting in the home to LED (house built in 67, full of regular bulbs, and just moved in) but the pulsing happened across both types of lighting. 
-ThreePhaseEel, I used the kettle on a new circuit and there was no pulsing.

Comment: I think it might be a good time to call back the electrician that upgraded your panel.  Either a loose connection on a circuit or on half of the panel.  Would almost bet that the new circuit you tried the kettle on is on the other half of the panel.  The lights that pulsed and the first kettle circuit are on the same side.

Comment: crip659, you are correct. The new circuit is on the other half of the panel and the lights that pulsated are all on the other. I will be calling them and I will provide an update.